# How can I find the size of a PNG image with GraphicsMagick c++ API?

Tags: c++, png, graphicsmagick

I am using GraphicsMagick++ API and have successfully read in an image, but I want to make sure it is giving me the correct information, so I would like to report the size of the image.

How can I find the size (Height, Width) of the image?

Furthermore, I would like to read the PNG file to a (Nx,Ny,3) array of integers (where Nx is the width and Ny is the height) and then do an analysis on the resulting matrix, perhaps making changes including resizing the matrix, and then write the resulting matrix to a separate PNG file.

Is this doable with GraphicsMagick++?

Comment: If GraphicsMagick++ can't do the things you want, OpenCV certainly can. Just make sure to read their tutorials. The learning curve is somewhat steep and there's a lot of bad info floating around.

Comment: couldn't you just open the file and seek end?

Comment: I'm *almost* tempted to close this as a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5762357/179910. That, however, cites libpng instead of GraphicsMagick C++, so I guess it's not quite a dupe (though the answer I gave there shows at least part of what you ask about here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*How can I find the size (Height, Width) of the image?*

GraphicsMagick++ calls those [`Image::rows()`](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/Image.html#rows) and [`Image::columns()`](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/Image.html#columns).

*I would like to ... Is this doable with GraphicsMagick++?*

Yes.  (And you can ask a specific question here if you get stuck with any of that.)

Comment: `Image::rows()` and `Image::cols()` work perfectly for what I was wanting. What is the best way to get the pixels into a `nrows x ncols x 3` array of type `int` to work on externally?

Comment: @Laurbert515 post a new question... you'll get a **much** bigger audience.  :)  Good luck!